# 'Hide' plane node under trigger image on ARKit 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, ios12

I am using ARKit 2.0 to detect trigger images and place planes and objects on top of it. I want a specific object to progressively appear from under my trigger image and position itself into its side. To do so, I run an animation to move position:

```
//Original Position
self.planeNode?.position = SCNVector3(0, -0.02, 0)

//New position
self.planeNode?.runAction(SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3(0.08, -0.05, 0), duration: 0.5))
```

However, the trigger image does not hide the planeNode and I can still see it on top of it, even though it is technically below.

I thought of replicating my trigger with a planeNode with its same image, but it would look weird when holding the trigger with one's hand or such.

Here are some images of the issue:

[image: Image below trigger, but showing on top]
[image: Image below trigger]

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution by using occlusion! Essentially I created a plane on top of my trigger that occludes everything behind it like so:

```
            //Set occlusion material
            let cardOcclusion = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
            let holdout = SCNMaterial()
            holdout.isDoubleSided = true
            holdout.diffuse.contents = CIColor.black
            holdout.colorBufferWriteMask = SCNColorMask(rawValue: 0)
            cardOcclusion.firstMaterial? = holdout
            let cardOcclusionNode = SCNNode()
            cardOcclusionNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
            cardOcclusionNode.geometry = cardOcclusion
            node.addChildNode(cardOcclusionNode)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by placing your UiimageView **object** in **viewObj** in below Code.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        let node = SCNNode()
        if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {
            let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.8)
            let material = SCNMaterial()
            material.diffuse.contents = viewObj
            plane.materials = [material]
            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
            node.addChildNode(planeNode)
        }
        return node
    }
```